# Parsing string - with regex or something similar?

Tags: php, regex, text-parsing

I'm writing routing class and need help. I need to parse $controller variable and assign parts of that string to another variables. Here is examples of $controller:

```
$controller = "admin/package/AdminClass::display"
//$path = "admin/package";
//$class = "AdminClass";
//$method = "display";

$controller = "AdminClass::display";
//$path = "";
//$class = "AdminClass";
//$method = "display";

$controller = "display"
//$path = "";
//$class = "";
//$method = "display";
```

This three situations is all i need. Yes, i can write long procedure to handle this situations, but what i need is simple solution with regex, with function preg_match_all

Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: Please be more spcific in your question regarding other parsing situations / other strings you may need to parse. First to second value could be done via replace/substring/split.

Comment: Why do you need to use a regex?

Comment: @CanSpice, to match this three situations, and then extract parts of string to variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following regex should accomplish this for you, you can then save the captured groups to `$path`, `$class`, and `$method`.

```
(?:(.+)/)?(?:(.+)::)?(.+)
```

Here is a Rubular:
http://www.rubular.com/r/1vPIhwPUub

Your php code might look something like this:

```
$regex = '/(?:(.+)\/)?(?:(.+)::)?(.+)/';
preg_match($regex, $controller, $matches);
$path = $matches[1];
$class = $matches[2];
$method = $matches[3];
```

Comment: Thanks! If you have any link where I can easy learn regex I will be very grateful :)

Comment: I use http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html as a cheat-sheet, and that website has some good tutorials.  Rubular is also really useful for quickly testing your regex.

Comment: This will also match `a/b`, which is not a legal input!

Answer (score 3):

This supposes that paths within the class, and the method name, can only contain letters.

The full regex is the following:

```
^(?:((?:[a-zA-Z]+/)*)([a-zA-Z]+)::)?([a-zA-Z]+)$
```

Two non capturing groups: the first one which makes all the path and class optional, the second which avoids the capture of individual path elements.

Explanation:

- a path element is one or more letters followed by a /: `[a-zA-Z]+/`;
- there may be zero or more of them: we must apply the `*` quantifier to the above; but the regex is not an atom, we therefore need a group. As we do not want to capture individual path elements, we use a non capturing group: `(?:[a-zA-Z]+/)*`;
- we want to capture the full path if it is there, we must use a capturing group over this `((?:[a-zA-Z]+/)*)`;
- the method name is one or more letters, and we want to capture it: `([a-zA-Z]+)`;
- if present, it follows the path, and is followed by two semicolons: `((?:[a-zA-Z]+/)*)([a-zA-Z]+)::`;
- but all this is optional: we must therefore put a group around all this, which again we do not want to capture: `(?:((?:[a-zA-Z]+/)*)([a-zA-Z]+)::)?`;
- finally, it is followed by a method name, which is NOT optional this time, and which we want to capture: `(?:((?:[a-zA-Z]+/)*)([a-zA-Z]+)::)?([a-zA-Z]+)`;
- and we want this to match the whole line: we need to anchor it both at the beginning and at the end, which gives the final result: `^(?:((?:[a-zA-Z]+/)*)([a-zA-Z]+)::)?([a-zA-Z]+)$`

Phew.

Comment: second regex returns class with method, AdminClass::display. I think that regex by F.J. can be used as second

Comment: Well, it really can be done with one regex and no errors, but it will be a very long regex and require even more explanation ;) I can cook it up and explain it all if you want.

Comment: Wouldn't this also match `a/b` and put it all into `$method`?

Comment: Yes, which is why I suggested to replace `.*` with more restrictive regexes. But see edit.

Comment: Done. Now with the full pizzazz :p

Answer (score -1):

```
        $pieces = explode('/',$controller); 
        $path = '';
        for($i = $i<$pieces.length-1; $i++)
        {
          if($i != 0)
             $path+='/';
          $path += $pieces[$i];
        }
        $p2 = explode(  '::',$pieces[$pieces.length-1]);
        $class = $p2[0];
        $method = $p2[1];
```